# Help with power buffer using capacitors

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buffer, supercapacitor

Looking for some help on how I might be able to add a power buffer of around 1 hour to an IC using super-capacitors, and be able to recharge it within 5~15 minutes after a power disconnect.

Looked online for a few days on how I could achieve this, but none of the scenarios I found really matched what I wanted to do. Thought i'd post here as it's likely a simple thing for someone with more knowledge.

Here's what I'm playing with right now:

- IC consumes around 1.2A at 5V
- Charging unit rated 24V 2A (revised from 5V 3A)
- Super-capacitors rated 250F at 2.5~3.8V, max 0.75A with peak of 5A(1s), and ESR of 50 mohms

Thinking 10~20 of these capacitors to get the 1 hour buffer.

Some questions:

- What elements and placement do I need to charge the capacitors within less than 15 minutes? (revised from 5 minutes)
- What is the best approach to downscale the voltage for super-capacitors?
- How do I avoid going over the amp rating of the capacitors?
- What's the best way to upconvert to the IC 5V 1.2A without significant loss?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fET9FZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You can't wire your capacitors under 5V, if there are 3.8 V max ... You need, at least, a "regulator" 5V -> 3.3 V. And an up-converter for the "load".

Comment: Any suggestions on a good regulator with low loss?

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. You need a backup supply, and have determined you must use supercaps, and now asking how to do it with supercaps. As proven by others, supercaps can't fit your specs and otherwise fit poorly. Please try to ask how to do X, instead of how to use supercaps to do X.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. For this particular case a battery isn't an option, and supercaps felt like a possibility, thus the question.

Comment: Your energy balance numbers don't work out. If the machine uses a certain amount of power in 60 minutes, and the charger makes 2.5 times as much power as the machine uses, there's 1.5 times left over for charging, so it would take at least 40 minutes to charge, just by the maths. Maybe that's actually okay, or maybe you would need a 10 times bigger charger.

Comment: Definitely a bigger charger, 24V 2A should probably cover it, with a longer charging time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a buck/boost or SEPIC converter and put the capacitors in series, you can squeeze out more energy. Step down conversion has better efficiency, because there are not so ugly high currents and copper losses to deal with.

There are some good capacitors with around 400-500 F and ESR below 5 mΩ available, that can accept >200 A of charge current.

Assume to have a grid of 8s2p of 450 F / 3 V, you initially have 24 V and a good converter will run down to 3 V. The usable energy is around 24.8 kJ for such a setup. 92 % over all converter efficiency assumed, there are 22.8 kJ available, just sufficient.

A quick charge of such a grid needs a strong balancer (or 8 chargers) to compensate tolerances in capacitance, but this could charge up in around 5 minutes at 10 A.

Comment: Thanks. Just one question, when you say "strong balancer", do you have any suggestion on what could be a good option for this?

Comment: @rcampos As soon as a capacitor reaches the rated voltage, all the current must be bypassed through a load parallel to it. At high charge currents this will produce a lot of heat, in my example 10 A at 3 V = 30 W, which is ugly to handle (power NPN + Z-diode + resistor). To avoid this, I would implement a voltage monitoring as used in BMS circuits to detect this situation and reduce the charge current to a much lower value. Typical BMS circuits have transistors and bleeding resistors on board, that can carry such a reduced current.

Comment: thanks, will have a look into that

Comment: In some cases I use a charger circuit with 8 identical secondary windings and schottky diodes. In such a circuit the capacitor with the lowest voltage receives the highest current because the windings are coupled on one core, and this is self balancing. Very useful when charging repaired e-bike battery packs.

Comment: Got it, this is very useful

Answer (score 1):

1.2 A at 5 V for 1 hour is 21.6 kJ. Total energy in your 250 F super capacitor is 1.8 kJ, assuming you can discharge them down to 0 V. You will need at least 20 of them.

> What elements and placement do I need to charge the capacitors within less than 5 minutes?

A 30 A current source. Even with 10 in parallel, this is above their rating. You need to look for a better solution, probably better supercapacitors.

Comment: On 30A current source being above their rating, it there a way to work around this? I can work with some loss if that was the trade-off.

Comment: @rcampos a simple workaround would be even more caps to spread the charge out. If you multiplied them by 4 you still wouldn't have a 5 minute charge... but in one hour you'd have only used 1/4 of the energy and you could do a 1/4 as long charge :) but then you'd be spending 4 times the money on capacitors that you actually need, but it's an easy work around other than buying different ones

Comment: From the comments, 5 minutes will likely be unrealistic, with 15 to 20 minutes something more achievable, and perhaps as you say, add more to ensure a bigger buffer.

Comment: I calculate 1.8 kJ for 250 F and 3.8 V using 1/2 C V², so 10 are not enough.

Comment: @Jens Ops! Forgot the 1/2. I’ll edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Supercaps is a bad choice IMO for this application, and unfortunately, your numbers don't add up.

If your IC draws 1.2A at 5V = 6W, then to charge a capacitor bank with enough charge to last an hour, in 5min would need at least 6W * 60/5 = 60W, and that would be for a lossless system. There's no way to make this work with a 15W input.

A 20-super capacitor bank, would be large, possibly a bit dangerous, but also difficult to create properly. You start to get problems with the resitance of your wires, and connections in general. You'd have to do some good maths to make this work.

I'd recommend you look at a battery for this. A single-cell, 3A or so battery should be fine even with some losses (do the math though). Then you just need a charger, a regulator to step up from the battery to 5V, and some kind off switching to connect the battery when you're supply drops. This still doesn't give your charge in 5min spec, as most batteries are happy only charging at 1C. You could increase your battery to 36A, but then you'd need to increase your input power.

Comment: Thanks for the note on the charger, this is something that can easily be changed, to something like 24V 3A. Size isn't an issue, but your mention on being dangerous and needing good math makes me a bit cautious. Battery isn't an option for this as it could only be replaced after 5 years, and most would not be working by then under a continuous operation. I'll take your points and think a bit more on it.

Comment: @rcampos If size isn't an issue and you only need a few years life span, put in two batteries and switch to the spare if the first dies.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, thanks.